# difference between: [ScaffoldColumn (false)] and [Display (AutoGenerateField = false)]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, data-annotations, scaffolding, mvc-editor-templates

To render HTML in my edit view, I use the helper `@Html.EditorForModel()`.

**My model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
[Display(Name = "Nome completo")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo é obrigatório")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "A {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} characteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Senha")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirmar senha")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A nova senha e a confirmação da senha não conincidem.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
[Display(Name = "Convidado")]
[UIHint("IsGuest")]
public bool IsGuest { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("IsGuest", true, ErrorMessage = "Campo é obrigatório")]
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public string CodeGuest { get; set; }
```

Property: `CodeGuest` should not be created by the helper `@Html.EditorForModel()`.  (I would like to create it manually.)

Reading on the Internet, I found several points and would like to know the difference.

Remembering that I do not want it to be hidden, this field will only be created by this

**EditorTemplates (IsGuest.cshtml):**

```
@using BindSolution.AndMarried.Model;
@model BindSolution.AndMarried.Models.RegisterModel
@Html.EditorFor(e => e.IsGuest)
<span>TESTE</span>
@Html.EditorFor(e => e.CodeGuest)
```

Question:

What is the difference between: `[ScaffoldColumn (false)]` and `[Display (AutoGenerateField = false)]`

Why can not I make `[Display (AutoGenerateField = false)] have the effect: 'do not generate the HTML field when calling`@Html.EditorForModel()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EditorForModel()` and `DisplayForModel()` Html helper methods makes decision of rendering view of the properties of the current Model based on the `ViewData.ModelMetadata`. The default `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` sets the properties of ModelMetadata based on the DataAnnotation attributes.

`ScaffoldColumnAttribute.Scaffold` affects two properties of  `ModelMetadata` i.e. '`ShowForDisplay`' and '`ShowForEdit`'.

`DisplayAttribute` does not affects the above two properties of `ModelMetadata`.

That is why these two attributes do not have the same effect on generating Html.

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to know the difference, the following is from MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411771(v=vs.95).aspx

"AutoGenerateField - A value that indicates whether the field is included in the automatic generation of user-interface elements such as columns. This value is used by the DataGrid control."

From this it appears that this particular property is meant for DataGrid only.